# Importing external libraries in Protege?

Tags: java, netbeans, owl, protege

I’m working on a Protege plugin, but I can’t get Protege to accept an
external library required by my plugin. The whole plugin depends on this external library but I wasn't able to find any solution for my problem.
I have successfully built a simple Protege plugin using Netbeans. However, when I try to add more complex functions contained in the external library that I need to use, the plugin no longer loads into Protege. Unfortunately no further
details are contained in the Protege log, the only thing that the log says is that “Plugin was not successfully started”.
Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: maven-bundle-plugin has to be configured appropriately (you should use Maven or Gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely scenario is that the library has not been included in the plugin build - it needs to be declared as an OSGi dependency in the manifest.mf file of your plugin and added to the bundles folder in Protege (if the library is available as an OSGi bundle) or embedded in the plugin file itself.

How to do that varies depending on your build process (Maven? Gradle? Or another?).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using Maven. What's the best way to do what you suggested?

Comment: as I said in my comment, use Maven Bundle Plugin and read their documentation. This should help

Comment: @aka_dudy For an example of OSGi packaging of a plugin with many dependencies, you can look at owlapi/osgidistribution/pom.xml. It creates the OWLAPI plugin Protege already uses. https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/osgidistribution/pom.xml (any mistakes in that file are my own fault, I might add)